# NoSuchMethodError: Class 'List<dynamic>' has no instance method 'cast' with matching arguments

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to fetch Articles from my API servers,but i get `NoSuchMethodError: Class 'List<dynamic>' has no instance method 'cast' with matching arguments` error. Does anybody know how can i solve it?

```
 List<Article> posts;
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse("$SERVER_IP/api/articles/?format=json"),
    headers: <String, String>{"Authorization" : "Token ${globaltoken}"},);
  final parsed = jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes)).cast<String,dynamic>();
  posts = parsed.map<Article>((json) => Article.fromJSON(json)).toList();
  return posts;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use cast() in the first place, because a nearby operation (in this case the parsed.map) already uses cast() for you and thus casts your desired type (Article). Omitting cast<String,dynamic>() should solve your error.

Please also refer to the dart documentation:

1. https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#dont-use-cast-when-a-nearby-operation-will-do
2. https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#avoid-using-cast